# Save WindowState and restore it after reboot /relogin

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, system-shutdown

I am working on a WPF application that should store its window state (normal / minimized) - even if the system is shutting down or loggin off.

The WindowClosing event is used to store the state. The problem is, that shutdown/log off enforces the window to close. Therefore, the window state is always minimized after reboot.

- Is there a safe way to check if the system is shutting down? (I tried `Environment.HasShutdownStarted`, but id didnt work).
- Is there a way to get notified about window state changes other than the WindowClosing event?

[Edit]
The answers of the question, marked as dublicate, are not satisfying:

- `SystemEvents.SessionEnding` is not a proper solution because the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says: "If you are using SessionEnding in a Windows form to detect a system logoff or reboot, there is no deterministic way to decide whether the Closing event will fire before this event."
- `GetSystemMetrics(SM_SHUTTINGDOWN)` may work (i didn't test it), but it requires PInvoke and I prefer a managed solution.
- So finally, the suggestion from d.moncada (using the `Application.SessionEnding` event) is the the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a safe way to check if the system is shutting down? (I tried
>   Environment.HasShutdownStarted, but id didnt work).

Do you want to know when the system (computer) is shutting down, or the application?

If it's the application, you can use `Window.Closing` event.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx).

If it's for the system, you can listen to the `Application.SessionEnding` event.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.sessionending.aspx).

> Is there a way to get notified about window state changes other than
>   the WindowClosing event?

Have you taken a look at the `StateChanged` event of the `Window`?

More info, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.statechanged(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Yes, and during machine shutdown, it is fired with state Minimized as the OP more or less indicates.

Comment: Thanks, Application.SessionEnding is a proper event that can be used to indicate if windows is shutting down.